# Apple Sandboxing technology-- How to grant/deny hardware access

Tags: xcode, macos, sandbox

sandbox-exec is agreat utility on Mac OS systems, very similar to Apparmor on Linux systems.

I usually run it using the standard command line format: `sandbox-exec -f profile_file  my_bin_app`.

My question is: how to grant some application an access to some system hardware resources in my sandbox profile file, like camera, bluetooth, or microphone (may be other things as well), in a way that's very similar to Xcode entitlements for accessing systems resources when developing your own app on mac.

Comment: Check http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/2170/sandbox-corners or examples in /usr/share/sandbox

Comment: Thanks .. but nothing relevant to my question